# Is there a function in R Studio to create an interactive map using NYC zip codes?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-leaflet

I have a dataset that has NYC Zip codes, and in a different dataset, I have lat and long codes. I am aware that I can use Leaflet to create an interactive but when I try run it on the 167K rows of data, R Studio freezes and struggles to load the data. I done that using the below code

```
leaflet(nyctest) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lat = ~Latitude, lng = ~Longitude
```

My question, is there a way to create an interactive map using the New York City Zip codes?

Example of the zip codes data:

11001,
11021,
11050,
11101,
11102,
11103,
11104,
11105

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This can be done via a shiny app. See here: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html

Comment: I am very new to R so not really sure how to understand it but I dont see in that link where it uses ZIP codes to map?

Comment: It doesn't. I'm just answering that it is possible to build a shiny app that provides an interactive use of a leaflet map.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesnt exactly help towards my question, although thanks for your reply